# Execute an .exe from ASP.NET Page using c#

Tags: asp.net

I am working on a web based application. I want to call an .exe from a page. I have added some line of code for this 
But when button clicked the Console windows appears and displays an exception saying that -- Unhanded Exception : System.NUllRefrenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of the object.

Can somebody help me to run the exe...

Thanks,
Sanjay

Comment: There is no way anyone can debug this with the provided information.

Comment: That won't actually work.  You need to learn the difference between the client and the server.

Comment: Maybe with an active-x ?

Comment: can you share with us your line of code ? and what are the .exe have as input, what as output, what is the goal of this .exe

Comment: Which object is null?  Use your debugger to find out.  To elaborate on SLaks' comment... What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  Do you want your web page to run an executable on the client machine?  Do you want users to use the web page to initiate an executable on the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example how to do it:

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(@"c:\yourProgram.exe", @"-p customParam");
procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
proc.Start();
string result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```